# Returing Method from method in javascript

Tags: javascript, overriding, magento2, mixins, magento-2.3

I have a module (let's call it 'infos') that is written like this

```
/* infos module */
define([], function() {
    'use strict';

    return function() {
        // some code here

        return {
            text: 'hehe',
            isEditable: function() {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

this module is then required in another module and called like this infos().isEditable() and will allow me to show or hide a button.

I have the possibility to do a mixin (magento2) of the base infos module and amend some alterations of methods in this module.

I am trying to modify the isEditable() to return true, but I can do it only in the MIXIN.

this is a simplified version of what I am trying to do:
https://jsfiddle.net/mu1oykad/

Comment: Reassign `returnObject`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance - Hard to see how that fits *"without modifying the function"*. :-) I mean, sure, you're talking about *replacing* the function, but...

Comment: Yeah, since function code is immutable after being declared, so reassigning it is the only other thing I can think of

Comment: *"without modifying the function"* Clearly we have to modify **something**. What are the limits? For that matter, what function are you referring to that we can't modify, `returnObject` or `isEditable`? **Why** can't we modify the function? Why the need to do this in the first place?

Comment: the function is not reachable, it is defined in another module and called by another module, I only have to possibility to intercept it within a wrapper function.

Comment: @pandreipopi - "intercept" it how? Show us.

Answer (score 0):

You have a function `isEditable` that is hardwired to return `false`, but you want to call it and have it return `true` without changing any of the wiring. Not possible.

Even if you precede the call with `!` and then that will give you the opposite, but the call itself is still returning `false` as in `!false` which is `true`.

In short:

```
!returnObject().isEditable()    // true
```

Comment: But i think the OP wants to change part of a library so that other dependencies to it, not just his, reflect this change.

Comment: Yes, it's obvious the OP doesn't want to do the above.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know what the need of kind of these functions. But to do so, you can create a new function which calls `isEditable` like this way

```
function notTrueOrNotFalse () {
return !returnObject().isEditable();
}
```

I do not know if what you are asking, but I hope it helps.